# How do I change a str() type to make my program know I am talking about an object?

Tags: string, python-3.x, types, format

I am about to make a database for fun. But I've got stuck at this point.

I am trying to make my search function more optimal. So I am trying to do this:

The error is as I remember. attributeerror 'str' object has no attribute 'print_info'

```
if password == "xxxx":
    person = input("Who are you searching for? ")
    if person == "Everyone":
        print("Searching for everyone...")
        info = input("What do you want to know about everyone? ")
        if info != "Job" and info != "Salary" and info != "Age" and info != "Email" and info != "Sex" and info != "Everything":
            print("No info was found")
        else:
            for key, value in employeeDict.items():
                print("")
                key.print_info(str(info))
    else: 
        print("Searching for", person + "...")
        info = input("What do you want to know about " + str(person) + "? ")
        if info != "Job" and info != "Salary" and info != "Age" and info != "Email" and info != "Sex" and info != "Everything":
            print("No info was found")
        else:
            person.print_info(str(info))
else:
    print("Access denied")
```

My "everyone" search function works fine but the function where I need to find one explicit employee gives me an attribute error because the "person" variable is formatted as a string. I was wondering if it was possible to format the person variable to make python know it is an object.

All of my code looks like this.

```
import datetime
from employeeVariables import *
from employeeClass import *

Name1 = Employee("Name1", "Lastname1", "Fullname1", "CEO", "75%", str(Name1BirthDate) + " " + "(" + str(int(Name1Age.days/365.25)) + " years and " + str(int(Name1Age.days % 365.25)) + " days)", "1_" + str(Name1BirthDate), "Male") 
Name2 = Employee("Name2", "Lastname2", "Fullname2", "Co. Founder", "25%", str(Name2BirthDate) + " " + "(" + str(int(Name2Age.days/365.25)) + " years and " + str(int(Name2Age.days % 365.25)) + " days)", "1_" + str(Name2BirthDate), "Male")


employeeDict = {Name1: Name1.ID, Name2: Name2.ID}

password = input('''Enter password to access the database
Password: ''')

if password == "xxxx":
    person = input("Who are you searching for? ")
    if person == "Everyone":
        print("Searching for everyone...")
        info = input("What do you want to know about everyone? ")
        if info != "Job" and info != "Salary" and info != "Age" and info != "Email" and info != "Sex" and info != "Everything":
            print("No info was found")
        else:
            for key, value in employeeDict.items():
                print("")
                key.print_info(info)
    else: 
        print("Searching for", person + "...")
        info = input("What do you want to know about " + str(person) + "? ")
        if info != "Job" and info != "Salary" and info != "Age" and info != "Email" and info != "Sex" and info != "Everything":
            print("No info was found")
        else:
            for key in employeeDict.items():
                if key == person: 
                    key.print_info(info)
                else:
                    print("The employee doesn't exist in the database")
else:
    print("Access denied")
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please always post the complete traceback of the error.

Comment: I will do that as soon as I get home. It is an attribute error I think. I will edit it soon

Comment: I think this is the error. attributeerror 'str' object has no attribute 'print_info'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've found a solution to the problem. I am not sure whether it is the best but it works right now.

I figured out that I didn't need my dict(employeeDict) to have the value Employee.ID. Instead I changed the key to be a string and my value to be the Employee. I can now match my input string with the key and make it print the value for that key.

Thx for the help

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to make a for loop with all the keys from your dictionary and say

```
If key == person
    Key.print__info(info)
```

I think this would work.

Comment: I have just tried this but it doesn’t seem to work proberly. The person variable is still not formatted the same way as the key so the key can’t equal person

Comment: Oh I see, will think of a new solution then.